# read files from subdirectories

Tags: r, read.csv

I have subdirectories named from "0001" to "0999", in each there is a file named "abc.csv".
How do I read all those files in a list?

Here is my approach so far:

```
abcs <- list()
for(i in seq_len(999))
  eval(parse(text=paste0("abcs[[",i,"]] <- read.csv('~/mydir/0000",i,"/abc.csv')")))
```

However, I have to do this separately for each amount of leading zeros.

There must be an easier way, thanks.
I know there is also the 'list.dir()' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the recursive argument in `list.files`

```
list_of_files <- list.files("~/mydir/", pattern = ".csv", recursive = T)
list_results <- lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: very nice, thanks. As I have other csv files in these directories besides abc.csv, I specified pattern="abc.csv"

Comment: you can also use `fread` from the `data.table` package, if you need faster reads.

Answer (score 0):

how about this? sprintf("%04d", n) pads zeros in front of a number to a required length

```
abcs <- lapply(1:999, function(n) read.csv(paste0(sprintf("%04d", n),"/abc.csv")))
```